# Cannot send message to MSMQ queue when destination server's domain name is specified

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a wcf msmq service. I try to send a message to it. Delivery fails is I specify server's domain name in endpoint address. If it contains ip or netbios name - everything is fine. I am able to ping the sever by it's domain name. DNS server is also reachable and has the needed entry. The messages are left in the system dead-letter queue. Any workarounds?

The client and the service are on the same machine. And it really seems like the message is really delivered, but the queue lookup fails. When I open destination queue properties I see that the queue name is comp_name\private$\my_queue. The messages in dead queue have destination comp_name**.com**\private$\my_queue. May be this is it?